# Opacity of images in TikZ with beamer

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, graphics, transparency

I'm creating some slides and want to integrate a (pixel) graphic in a TikZ picture with opacity less than 1. I expect this code to work:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz,graphicx}

\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}{test}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \node[opacity=0.7] at (0,0) 
        {\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image.png}};
      \node at (4,0) {Some text};
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, the whole picture vanishes:

[image]

Note that the same TikZ code works as expected with `article`. If I use `opacity=0.7` on a text node, not the image, it also works.

What to do?

I use Evince and pdflatex from TeXlive 2013 on GNU/Linux in case that's relevant.

Comment: Here, the result of your MWE is correct! (the transparent image on the left of "some text"). Have you tried to update your distribution?

Comment: I have `beamer` 3.33 and `tikz` 3.0.0. Will run an upgrade...

Comment: @PaulGaborit Ah, turns out I lied; I'm still on 2013. I'll have to perform a full reinstall which is inopportune right now. I'll check back when I've upgraded.

Comment: @PaulGaborit Unless I forget: thanks for checking!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upgrading to TeXlive 2014 (with the latest packages as of today) solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly the same as the minimum example, but it turns out this can also happen if the `transparent` package is loaded.

Removing the `transparent` package from my document caused the `opacity` setting for `tikz` `node`s to work as expected.